# ImportError: cannot import name 'pybindIETFXMLEncoder'

Tags: python

I am new to Python, I am using pytest to run a test script.
I don't know how to fix this. I have tried install pip install pyangbind it says - requirement already satisfied. I am kind of stuck what to do next.

However, I am facing this issue -

```
#pytest test.py
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
test.py:12: in <module>
    from config.generator import NcConfig
../config/generator.py:4: in <module>
    from .base import PybBase
../config/base.py:9: in <module>
    from pyangbind.lib.serialise import pybindIETFXMLEncoder
E   ImportError: cannot import name 'pybindIETFXMLEncoder'
```

The python freeze tells me - 
Here are the dependencies on my virtual py environ

```
 $pip freeze
    asn1crypto==0.24.0
    atomicwrites==1.1.5
    attrs==18.1.0
    bcrypt==3.1.4
    bitarray==0.8.3
    certifi==2018.4.16
    cffi==1.11.5
    chardet==3.0.4
    cryptography==2.3
    defusedxml==0.5.0
    enum34==1.1.6
    idna==2.7
    jira==1.0.15
    lxml==4.2.3
    more-itertools==4.2.0
    ncclient==0.5.4
    oauthlib==2.1.0
    paramiko==2.4.1
    pathlib2==2.3.2
    pbr==4.0.4
    pluggy==0.6.0
    py==1.5.4
    pyang==1.7.5
    pyangbind==0.8.1
    pyasn1==0.4.4
    pycparser==2.18
    PyNaCl==1.2.1
    pytest==3.5.1
    regex==2018.7.11
    requests==2.19.0
    requests-oauthlib==1.0.0
    requests-toolbelt==0.8.0
    six==1.11.0
    tabulate==0.8.2
    urllib3==1.23
```

The python version is 3.5.2.

```
$python --version
Python 3.5.2
```

Answer (score 4):

The name you are attempting to import from `pyangbind.lib.serialise` does not exist in version 0.8.1. That version was released in May-2018, while the type was only [committed to the repository](https://github.com/robshakir/pyangbind/pull/211) in Jun-2018.

If you wish to use this type you will need to use as yet unreleased code from the [source repository](https://github.com/robshakir/pyangbind).

See the [pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#git) for how to do this.